# Changing a simple banner animation text using a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, animation, actionlistener, jtextfield

I'm doing an assignment for just a simple banner that moves across a JPanel and I got it working and thought I would add the ability for the user to enter a message in a JTextField to change the banner's message.  I'm having issues though.

I just can't seem to be able to figure out how to use the JTextField to change the message variable.  I figured I needed a ActionListener but what I have is just not working (nothing happens after you hit enter in the JTextField).

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Banner extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private int x = 0, y = 100;
    private static JTextField messageField;
    private String message;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame JF = new JFrame();
    Banner firstMessage = new Banner("Type a message in the text field to change the banner");
    Banner newMessage = new Banner("");
    messageField = new JTextField();        
    JF.add(firstMessage);
    JF.add(messageField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JF.setSize(800, 400);
    //Add banner message
    firstMessage.start();

    //JF.add(newMessage);

    JF.setVisible(true);
    JF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

//Banner constructor
public Banner(String m) {
    message = m;    
    x = getSize().width + 300;  
}

//Start timer thread 
public void start() {
    TimerTest timer = new TimerTest(this);
    timer.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(getBackground());
    //set background color red
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    //Move message until end of message reaches the end of screen
    if(x > -300) {
        x -= 6;
    }
    else {
        x = getSize().width + 10;
    }
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString(message, x, y);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if(event.getSource() == messageField) {
        message = (messageField.getText());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: message.equals(messageField.getText()) should be `message = messageField.getText()`. Also, call `super.paintComponent` in your `paintComponent` method before you do any custom painting

Comment: Shouldn't your actionPerformed method be responding to your Timer and updating the position of your message

Comment: Yeah I had it as message = but I've been playing around with it.  Thanks I forgot about super.paintcomponent().

Comment: Meaning it should be in my TimerTest class?

Comment: No, sorry I mistook your timer class for a Swing Timer

Comment: Oh I see.  Yeah I just called the other class with the new thread TimerTest, I didn't post it because I didn't want to post too much code and it didn't seem necessary. Any tips Mad?

Comment: Swing's not thread safe, so a Swing `Timer` would be better. See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Oh ok.  I was just following the books tutorials.  I'll look at using an actual timer.

Comment: Any tips on changing the Banner with the JTextField?

Comment: Yep, first comment. Don't forget to register `this` as an `ActionListener` to the field as well

Comment: Ok thanks.  I could be going crazy but I don't see that in your first comment?  lol

Comment: Hey Mad, sorry to keep bothering you.  When you say register I'm assuming you're meaning as an instance of the event handler class like....addActionListener(this);  I'm not sure where or how to do that.  When I've used the action listener before I was adding a action to a button like...button.addActionListener(handler); where handler is a object of a Handler class I created specifically for the action listener.  So I'm confused on how and where to use this?

Comment: messageField.addActionListener(this) (also, sorry, I'm reading this on my phone and it's less then intuitive :P)

Comment: No worries I appreciate all the help.  I have that in my main method and I get an error that says cannot invoke this as a static reference

Comment: Sorry, it should be firstMessage not this :P

Comment: Oh ok.  So I don't need the newMessage object at all then?   When adding the firstMessage as an action listener it's going to display that first message set up by the constructor and also listen for anything added to the JTextField?   Sorry if I'm being a pain in the ass, I just want to make sure I understand what I'm doing not just doing it.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: No, I can't see any need for it

Comment: Ok gotcha.  Thanks again!